# Can SSIS project configuration values be configured via some sort of automation?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I'm trying to figure out how to automate setting up configuration of a project.

So far, I've had the most luck using T-Sql to deploy the projects and I can get the values set for a project with the `catalog.get_parameter_values` stored procedure. However, it is not obvious which stored procedure I'd use to set the values.

We aren't currently using environment variables, but not opposed to it (the SSIS packages are installed within the environment, so they don't have to switch). Also, if there is another way to automate, I'm open to that too. I did try MOM but could not find the DLLs needed nor any info on how to install them. I haven't tried `isdeploymentwizard.exe`.

#### Clarification

This is about how to automate **deployment** of a SSIS project to a server. I have a bunch of projects authored and I have the `.ispac` files for each. I have (at this point) automated deployment using T-Sql scripts.

What I am missing is some way to setup project level configuration via a script. The configuration of each project can be challenging and time consuming and is completely manual.

I am not using environments, because there is only one environment (the one it's installed on).

Answer (score 0):

hi you can use the Agent job task in SSIS and define the configuration in file that you need to run and define this file in the agent job task .

Comment: Can you add some useful links?

Comment: You should edit your existing answer, not add a second answer.

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx
SSIS How to Create an ETL Package
it is the best source for SSIS Projects